# How to run Kafka with SASL_SSL

Tags: apache-kafka

I have strange error in kafka log:

```
2023-12-21 00:22:17,254] DEBUG Setting SASL/SCRAM_SHA_256 server state to FAILED (org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.internals.ScramSaslServer)
[2023-12-21 00:22:17,256] DEBUG Set SASL server state to FAILED during authentication (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
[2023-12-21 00:22:17,257] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9092-127.0.0.1:63474-6) (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

My server.priperties:

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092

sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.keystore.location=C:/apps/certs/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=sepultura1
ssl.key.password=sepultura1
ssl.truststore.location=C:/apps/certs/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=sepultura1
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

My Kafks server jaas.conf:

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="user"
   password="sepultura1";
};
Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user="user"
    password="sepultura1";
};
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
username="user"
password="sepultura1";
};
```

My zookeper.properties:

```
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl

zookeeper.authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
```

My zookeeper jaas.conf:

```
Client{
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
username=“user”
password=“sepultura1”;
};
Server{
     org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
     user_user="sepultura1";
};
```

My Kafka version is kafka_2.13-3.6.0. Can someone give me a point how to solve this issue? I try to google it, but without any findings. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find solution:

1.) start with new installation of Kafka.

2.) Start zookeeper and kafka Brooker

3.) Add users to zookeeper

```
kafka-configs --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=kafka123]"  --entity-type users --entity-name stocks_consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181
kafka-configs --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=kafka123]"  --entity-type users --entity-name stocks_producer --zookeeper localhost:2181
kafka-configs --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=kafka123]"  --entity-type users --entity-name admin --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

4.) Add user to Kafka brooker:

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=sepultura1],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=sepultura1]" --entity-type users  --entity-name user
```

5.) Add zookeeper.jass.conf:

```
Server {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_super="adminsecret"
       user_admin="kafka123";
};
```

6.) Add to zookeeper.propertiers:
authProvider.sasl=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider

7.) Add server.jass.conf:

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="user"
   password="sepultura1";
};
Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="kafka123";
};
```

8.) Edit server.properties:

```
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256

listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092

sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.keystore.location=C:/apps/certs/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=sepultura1
ssl.key.password=sepultura1
ssl.truststore.location=C:/apps/certs/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=sepultura1
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

9. Add this to zookeeper-server-start.bat (On windows)

   set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/apps/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/config/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf
10. Add this into kafka-server-start.bat (On windows)

    set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/apps/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf

And then it should run (At least error with failed autorization is gone).

Comment: Well done. Upvoted. I did emphasize the importance of creating SCRAM users in Zookeeper using `kafka-configs.sh`. And the need for consistency in SASL configuration across all Kafka brokers and clients, which you did by adding a user to the Kafka broker with SCRAM credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```bash
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
| Kafka Broker      |          | Zookeeper Server  |
| - SASL_SSL        | <------> | - SASL Auth       |
| - SCRAM-SHA-256   |          |                   |
| - Keystore/Trusts.|          |                   |
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
```

I would start by checking out and following the tutorial "[Lab 8.4: Kafka and SASL SCRAM](https://gist.github.com/gilmacieljr/1668443473e14c69284b1453f975e138)".

When I compare your setup with that tutorial, I see some differences which could be important in your case:

- you do not mention the creation of [SCRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_Challenge_Response_Authentication_Mechanism) users in Zookeeper using `kafka-configs.sh`, as shown in the tutorial. This could be a critical missing step.

  ```bash
  kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh \
  --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=kafka123]" \
  --entity-type users --entity-name stocks_consumer \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181
    # Repeat for each user (stocks_producer, admin)
  ```
- The tutorial configures both `PLAINTEXT` and `SASL_SSL` listeners, while you only mention SASL_SSL.
- The tutorial uses different users for different roles and applications, whereas you seem to use a single user for all roles.
- The tutorial maintains consistency across all brokers and clients, which is crucial for proper SSL/TLS setup: all brokers and clients should reference the same keystore and truststore files, or equivalent files with the same certificates. The passwords for keystores and truststores should be consistent across all configurations. All SSL-related parameters, like `ssl.client.auth`, `ssl.key.password`, etc., should be consistently set across brokers and clients.
- You do not detail the consumer and producer settings for SASL_SSL, which are explicitly configured in the tutorial.

---

> I try to remove zookeeper.properties for SASL and also removed `zookeeper.jaas.conf`.
> I created users in zookeeper, but now It fails on :
>
> ```
> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: 
>    KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /consumers
> ```

The [`AuthFailedException`](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.3/apidocs/zookeeper-server/org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException.AuthFailedException.html) from Zookeeper should indicate an issue with authentication, meaning, a mismatch or a problem in the authentication setup between Kafka and Zookeeper.

Since you removed the Zookeeper SASL configuration, but added user creation in Zookeeper, there might be inconsistencies in how authentication is being handled.

When [SASL is enabled for Zookeeper](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/zk-security.html#zk-authentication-overview), it expects clients (including Kafka brokers) to authenticate using the specified mechanism. Removing the `zookeeper.properties` and `zookeeper.jaas.conf` for SASL while creating users in Zookeeper can lead to a mismatch in expected authentication methods.

If you are using SASL for Kafka, you should also use SASL for Zookeeper to maintain consistency in security protocols. Consider reinstating the SASL configuration in `zookeeper.properties` and `zookeeper.jaas.conf`.

Make sure Kafka's `server.properties` and `jaas.conf` are correctly set up for SASL and match the authentication mechanism expected by Zookeeper. The usernames and passwords should correspond to those configured in Zookeeper.
As an example, see "[Authenticate with SASL using JAAS](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html)".
If the error is related to Kafka consumers (as indicated by `/consumers` in the error message), make sure your Kafka consumer configurations (potentially in client-side `jaas.conf`) are correctly set up for SASL authentication.

If you are creating users in Zookeeper, make sure these are the users Kafka brokers are configured to authenticate as in the Kafka `jaas.conf`.

Comment: I try to remove zookeeper.properties for SASL and also removed zookeeper.jaas.conf. I create users in zookeeper but now It fails on : org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /consumers